# Convex analysis question: Cone and convex hull

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

I'm reading a publication, where a small bit of convex analysis is used in one of the lemmas. I have Rockafellar's book, but I haven't found anything too helpful yet as I am pretty new to the area.

> **Lemma.** Let $I \subset \{1, \dots, n\}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with cardinality $\alpha = \#I$. Define a cone as
>
> $$C = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n  : \sum_{i \notin I} |x_i| \leq \sum_{i \in I} |x_i|\right\}.$$
> Then for a set
>
> $$ G = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{\{x_i \neq 0\}} \leq \alpha,~~||x|| = 1\right\},$$
> we have that
>
> $$ C \cap \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x|| = 1\} \subset 3 \cdot \text{Conv}(G),$$
> where $||\cdot||$ is the $L^2$ norm.

**Proof of Lemma Idea:** A Theorem in Rockafellar states that a convex hull is equal to the set of convex combinations of $H$, where for a vector $\lambda \geq 0$ we can define as

$$K(G) := \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \lambda_1 x_1 + \dots + \lambda_n x_n ~\text{a combination in}~G~\text{s.t.}~~\sum_i^n \lambda_i = 1\right\},$$

and $\text{Conv}(G) = K(G)$.

But I'm not sure how to proceed?

Comment: what is the publication?

Comment: It's to appear in a stats/machine learning journal. The paper was circulated in a seminar class I'm auditing. Let me see if I can find a link without a pay wall...

Comment: What is the question? What do you want to prove? the lemma or $conv(G)=K(G)$?

Comment: Lemma. I can prove $\text{Conv}(G) = K(G)$. My "thus far" is just how I was thinking of approaching the proof. Edited for clarity.